# AdapterDataObserver's onChange method works but shows the emptyView for a split second

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm currently using RecyclerView with MVVM databinding(well the databinding might not matter).
Anyway, what I'm trying to do is to show a certain layout view when the data in the recyclerView
is empty. It works wen I use the AdapterDataObserver onChanged(the following code). But the problem is that when I 
open my app, my Empty time view shows up only for a split second(like a glitch / flicks) then show the lists normally. I'm unable to fix the 
problem to not show this empty time view when a open the screen. Some sample example or code will be awesome!
I would love to hear from you !

Part of the code below

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

     viewModel = activity?.run {
         ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(ShopViewModel::class.java)
     } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")

     val adapter = ShopRecyclerAdapter(viewModel, mIndex))

     val emptyObserver = object : RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
         override fun onChanged() {
             val isEmpty = adapter.itemCount == 0
             val isfavImage = if (mIndex == 2) R.drawable.img_fav else R.drawable.img_none
             val isNoData = if (isEmpty || adapter == null) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
             val visibility = if (isEmpty || adapter == null) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
             binding.layoutSwipeRefresh.visibility = visibility
             binding.noneLayout.visibility = isNoData
             binding.noneLayout.item_coupon_none_im.setImageResource(isfavImage)
         }
     }
     adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(emptyObserver)
     emptyObserver.onChanged()


     val recyclerView: RecyclerView = binding.shopRecycleView
     val layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 1, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
     recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you get data for the list? Say you have a `loading state` that has just a loading spinner. After you get data for the list, register observer to display either empty view or populate the list

Comment: From the modelView from a repository using Retrofit

Comment: then you can register `emptyObserver` after server request. or call your `emptyObserver.onChanged()` after request comes back